# 5v to charge a 12 V battery pack (possible with this?)

Tags: batteries, 12v, 5v

[image]

Is it possible to charge a 12 V battery pack with a 5 V charger (say USB charger)?
With the follow conditions...

1. The charger will internally charge cell 1 upto 4.2 V, then switch to cell 2 and charge it upto 4.2 V and then cell 3 upto 4.2 V.
2. Maybe... it will then boost 5 V upto 12.5 V (I know with very little current) to equalize the cells.

Does this exist? or is it possible? regarless if it takes longer?

Comment: Also known as a balance charger.

Comment: Seems possible, but control circuit will be very complicated. Either way, cells are mostly charged at constant current with a voltage cutoff. Why not simply charge the cells separately with a TP4056 or similar modules and then connect them together. Equalization will occur during use.

Comment: Because the idea is to keep the source in 5V

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. You will need to switch both terminals of each cell individually for charging, while keeping the other terminals isolated. It must be done in a way that guarantees no shorts during switching. Doing this electronically will be difficult.

If you charge each cell to 4.2V and terminate at the same current (i.e let the charging cycle complete) then you won't need to 'balance' the cells because they will all be fully charged. However the charging process must not be stopped until all 3 cells have been fully charged.

Charging the pack will take 3 times longer than charging a single cell. This may take many hours.

Another way to do it is use 3 separate '5V' chargers (eg. TP4056) each powered by its own isolated 5V power supply. This would charge would all 3 cells at once without the complication of a switching circuit.

Comment: Yes, but will split the current. For example... a USB port with only 500ma will be maybe about 165ma per charger.

Comment: @Panamanian perhaps you missed where I said "each powered by **its own** isolated 5V power supply". Do I need to make this clearer?